# Why i can't start activity in my android app?

Tags: java, android

If i do some test on Samsung Galaxy 2 this code works:

```
for(int i = 0; i < all_ids.size(); i++)
{
    if(i == position)
    {
        System.out.println("Rabotaet if");
        String topic = null;

        String message_id = null;
        Intent activity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessageActivity.class);
        activity.putExtra(SESSION_ID, sess_id);
        activity.putExtra(DATE,date);
        activity.putExtra(TYPE,folder_type);
        activity.putExtra(TOPIC,all_subjects.get(i));
        activity.putExtra(MESSAGE_ID, all_ids.get(i));
        activity.putExtra(FROM, all_emails_address.get(i));
        startActivity(activity);
    }
}
```

But if I do this test on Samsung Tab 3, it's not working. And in debug I see this message:

```
04-14 12:27:10.760: W/System.err(24669): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 4, size is 0
```

Any ideas?

After update i've code:

```
            for(int i = 0; i < all_ids.size(); i++)
            {
                if(i == position)
                {
                    System.out.println("Rabotaet if");
                    String topic = null;

                    String message_id = null;
                    Intent activity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessageActivity.class);
                    activity.putExtra(SESSION_ID, sess_id);
                    activity.putExtra(DATE,date);
                    activity.putExtra(TYPE,folder_type);

                    if (i < all_ids.size())
                        activity.putExtra(MESSAGE_ID,all_ids.get(i));
                    if (i < all_subjects.size())
                        activity.putExtra(TOPIC,all_subjects.get(i));
                    if (i < all_emails_address.size())
                        activity.putExtra(FROM, all_emails_address.get(i));
                    startActivity(activity);    
                }   
            }
```

But now i've this error:

```
04-14 12:39:59.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26359): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 12:39:59.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26359): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gdes.earchive/com.gdes.earchive.MessageActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 12:39:59.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26359):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2249)
04-14 12:39:59.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26359):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2299)
04-14 12:39:59.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26359):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:154)
04-14 12:39:59.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26359):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1284)
04-14 12:39:59.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26359):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-14 12:39:59.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26359):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-14 12:39:59.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26359):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5306)
04-14 12:39:59.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26359):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 12:39:59.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26359):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-14 12:39:59.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26359):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1102)
04-14 12:39:59.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26359):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:869)
04-14 12:39:59.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26359):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-14 12:39:59.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26359): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 12:39:59.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26359):    at com.gdes.earchive.MessageActivity.onCreate(MessageActivity.java:37)
04-14 12:39:59.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26359):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5255)
04-14 12:39:59.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26359):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1097)
04-14 12:39:59.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26359):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2213)
04-14 12:39:59.480: E/AndroidRuntime(26359):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: check your array its size is zero and you are call at index 4th so log your array size and check it

Comment: Need more information than this. If you get an IndexOutOfBounds means that it's something wrong with all_ids.size(); EDIT: the problem is probably with all_subjects or all_emails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your loop is based on the size of `all_ids`. You're also using 2 other array-type of variables: `all_subjects` and `all_emails_address`. One of them has size of 0 (no elements).

You need to check their size before using them:

```
if (i < all_subjects.size())
    activity.putExtra(TOPIC,all_subjects.get(i));
if (i < all_emails_address.size())
    activity.putExtra(FROM, all_emails_address.get(i));
```

Comment: I have done some modification on my code, but now i have "unfortunately has stopped"

Comment: What is the exception this time?

Comment: @user3323180 That's a separate problem. Try to debug yourself, the problem is in line 5255. If you can't find a solution, ask a separate question. You should have one problem per question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have no data for the index 4 for one (or both) lists:

**all_subjects** or/and **all_emails_address**

Please insert some further checking on **all_subjects.size()** and **all_emails_address.size()**

The error caught in the logcat is quite clear: the index provided and based on size list all_ids could not reachabele also for other lists.

So is a good practice checking as possible the index of a list before use it

Comment: This answer is too short, and is at risk of being closed. Please add further explanation or content to assist readers.